# Index variable of an array in a for loop throwing error

Tags: javascript, arrays, luxon

I want to compare the start date of the curr_item array based on index, but im getting this particular error at the arrow marked line.Im not sure what the issue is :(

**0: Object
start_time: "2021-10-27T13:30:00.000+05:30"
end_time: "2021-10-27T13:45:00.000+05:30"
1: Object
start_time: "2021-10-27T13:46:00.000+05:30"
end_time: "2021-10-27T14:00:00.000+05:30"
2: Object
start_time: "2021-10-27T14:00:00.000+05:30"
end_time: "2021-10-27T15:02:00.000+05:30"**

```
for (let index = 0; index < possible_slots; index++) {
  if (
    curr_time.toMillis() ===
   -----> DateTime.fromISO(curr_item[index].start_time).toMillis() <-----
  ) {
    slotlist.push({
      start_time: DateTime.fromISO(curr_item[index].start_time).toISO(),
      end_time: DateTime.fromISO(curr_item[index].end_time).toISO(),
      name: `asd`
    });
  } else {
    slotlist.push({
      start_time: DateTime.fromISO((curr_item[index]).start_time).toISO(),
      end_time: DateTime.fromISO(curr_item[index].end_time).toISO(),
      hole: `true${index}`
    });

    curr_time = DateTime.fromISO(slotlist[slotlist.length - 1].end_time);
  }
  curr_item[index] = curr_item[index + 1];
}
```

Error: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'start_time')**

Answer (score 0):

There can be only two reasons for this:

1. Array which is according to your code curr_item is undefined.
   2.The index you are trying to access inside the curr_item array is not available in the array. meaning curr_item[index] gives undefined and when you try to access the start_time of the above statement it throws the error.